# How is 果岭 a loanword from the English "green" (i.e.: putting green)?

Tags: translation, loanwords

[MDBG](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqtm=0&wdqcham=2&wdqt=%E6%9E%9C%E5%B2%AD) has the following entry:

> 果岭
>   guǒ​lǐng​
>
> green (golf) (loanword)

果岭 doesn't really sound anything remotely like [green](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golf_course#Greens), 岭 especially doesn't match up with the end of *green*.

How did green become 果岭?

Comment: IMO if you cut off **uǒ​** from **guǒ​lǐng​** it’s a very close approximation of **green** (close as you can get for Mandarin). You just have to say **guǒ​lǐng​** by heavily de-stressing the first syllable.

Comment: Never heard of the word

Comment: @droooze Makes sense. By that estimation something like 格林 would have been much more apt.

Comment: You're right, but maybe it's a regional phonetic approximation rather than standard Mandarin.

Comment: The word 果岭 means **putting green**, see here: [果岭](http://baike.baidu.com/view/31392.htm), a term in golf.

Comment: 果岭 (putting ***green***) means: 球洞区 (***the green area where the hole located in***) in 高尔夫球场 (***a golf course***), 高尔夫球场的**球洞区**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you said in the comment, something like 格林 indeed would have been a better phonetic approximation. But the translation (even by sound) should also consider its meaning if possible. 岭 means hill or mountain in Chinese. And since a golf course resembles a hill for having ups and downs, 岭 would be more approriate to describe such an area. However I think 果 is purely phonetic.